# ImageButton triangle background

Tags: android, material-design, android-custom-view, android-vectordrawable

The task is to implement button of triangle shape. With elevation, shadows and ripple effect after pressing.

"add_button.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="96dp"
    android:height="96dp"
    android:viewportHeight="96"
    android:viewportWidth="96">

    <path
        android:pathData="M 0,0 L96,48, L0,96 Z"
        android:fillColor="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
</vector>
```

Adding this vector to imageButton

```
...
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/triangleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:translationZ="8dp"/>
...
```

The problem is I can't get rid of background square background
Ripple effect also occupies whole square, not only triangle.

[image]

Tried to solve it by setting background to null, but in this case button looks as triangle, but static - with no elevation and ripple effect.

Is it possible to create triangle button with shadows of triangle form and reacting to pressing in general?

Comment: add `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"` to the button, it makes the grey background disappear but the ripple effect will be circle, ik its not meet your requirement

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, @ErwinKurniawanA. Does not work properly. No shadows and, yes, ripple effect is circle.